Difficult Icosahedron and Dodecahedron Puzzles

If lightbulbs are placed at any two distinct vertices of a regular, i.e., perfectly symmetrical, dodecahedron, how many distinct patterns are possible, counting as one pattern any patterns that can be made to coincide with one another by merely rotating the dodecahedron in various ways as one solid object?
Suppose that lightbulbs are placed at any three distinct vertices of a regular, i.e., perfectly symmetrical, icosahedron, as illustrated in the figure to the right. How many distinct patterns can thereby be formed, counting as one pattern any patterns that can be made to coincide with one another by merely rotating the icosahedron in various ways as one solid object?

Am I right to think that these problems could be solved with Burnside's Lemma? If so, how would one go about that? Thanks!

The assignment of a single lightbulb on a vertex of a dodecahedron clealy can be rotated in such a way that this vertex points up. So there is just a single such choice.
When considering the dodecahedron with vertex pointing up, you would have 6 vertex layers orthogonal to that upright axis: the top point, the 3 neighbouring vertices, the 6 bottom vertices of the 3 top-vertex incident pentagons, and the same 3 layers, when counting from the bottom vertex instead. - If the second lightbulb would not be assigned to the diametral point (bottom vertex), the dodecahedron always could be rotated around that upright axis, so that this second lightbulb would point in direction to the viewer. Accordingly we imply have 5 potential placements for the second lightbulb: one each for any of the remaining (i.e. so far empty) vertex layers. We would call these distances A < B < C < D < E.
For the third lightbulb we get multiple possibilities within the given setup.
May those possibilities be oriented by lowest layer numbers. Then

0,1,1: essentially a single choice, yielding the mirror-symmetric triangle AAB.
0,1,2: a near, a medium, and a far choice; however the near one was already encountered in 1., the triangle ABB of the medium one has mirror symmetry, while that of the far one, ABC, not; thence we get still three possibilities up to rotation.
0,1,3: again a near (ABC, already encountered), medium (ACC, mirror-symmetric), and far (ACD, assymmetric, i.e. two orientations) solution; thus again 3 new possibilities.
0,1,4: two solutions (ACD, already encountered), and the triangle ADE within the mirror-plane of the dodecahedron itself, thus this triangle provides just a single further possibility).
0,1,5: single solution ADE was already encountered.
0,2,2: providing triangles ABB (already encountered), BBC, BBD (all mirror-symmetric, just a single contribution), and BBB (regular, again a single contribution).
0,2,3: ABC, BBC (all already encountered), BCC (mirror-symmetric), BCD (again two orientations), BCE (again hemi-facial, i.e. a single orientation only).
0,2,4: BBD (again) and BDD (both mirror-symmetric).
0,2,5: BCE again.
0,3,3: ACC (again), BCC (again), CCC, CCD.
0,3,4: ACD (again), BCD (again), CCD (again)
0,3,5: BCE only (clearly hemi-facial, thus a single orientation)
0,4,4: BDD only, but already encountered.
0,4,5: ADE only (again hemi-facial), but already encountered.

In total we get 1+3+3+1+0+3+4+1+0+2+0+1+0+0=19 unique triangles (including their enantiomorph forms).
--- rk
